# compile own ffmpeg filter

Tags: c++, gcc, filter, ffmpeg, compilation

I'm trying compile my own ffmpeg filter using official tutorial. My filter uses C++ code. I made header file and adapted my C++ function definition for C. Now I'm trying compile with command `make -j<libavfilter> ffmpeg`, but receiving an error message

> gcc -Llibavcodec -Llibavdevice -Llibavfilter -Llibavformat
> -Llibavresample -Llibavutil -Llibpostproc -Llibswscale -Llibswresample -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--warn-common -Wl,-rpath-link=libpostproc:libswresample:libswscale:libavfilter:libavdevice:libavformat:libavcodec:libavutil:libavresample
> -o ffmpeg_g fftools/ffmpeg_opt.o fftools/ffmpeg_filter.o fftools/ffmpeg_hw.o fftools/cmdutils.o fftools/ffmpeg.o  -lavdevice
> -lavfilter -lavformat -lavcodec -lswresample -lswscale -lavutil  -lm -pthread -lm -lm -lz -pthread -lm -lz -lm -lm -pthread -lm   libavfilter/libavfilter.a(vf_foobar.o): In function `filter_frame':
> /home/joeyes/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavfilter/vf_foobar.c:302:
> undefined reference to MyFunction.c
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
> *** [ffmpeg_g] Error 1

For compilation I added `OBJS-$(CONFIG_FOOBAR_FILTER) += vf_foobar.o MyCode.o` to /libavfilter/makefile

Also I put MyCode.h & MyCode.cpp to /libavfilter folder

Comment: My guess is that MyCode.cpp wasn't compiled. Did you add it to the makefile?

Comment: Make sure you don't forget to disable c++ name mangling with extern C keywords.

Comment: Yes, I added it to the makefile. As a result, the file is compiled (MyCode.o is exists in \libavfilter folder)

Comment: try running `make V=1` and check if MyCode.o is included in the "link" command.  (may need to re-run configure?)

Comment: I do make with the V=1 and placed the result in the original message

Comment: Did you REGISTER_FILTER your new filter in allfilter.c

Answer (score 0):

You did put things in these files right?

Here is an example of what I added to these for my own custom filter vf_apatechange.c

ffmpeg/libavfilter/Makefile

```
+OBJS-$(CONFIG_APATECHANGE_FILTER)              += vf_apatechange.o
```

ffmpeg\libavfilter\allfilters.c

```
extern AVFilter ff_vf_apatechange;
```

ffmpeg/libavfilter/filter_list.c

```
&ff_vf_apatechange,
```

Comment: Yeah, it was long time ago:) Seems right. But I didn't touch `filter_list.c` and probably it would be necessary to change `HEADERS` and `OBJS` in `Makefile`